# USB Device read file from android

Tags: android, usb-drive

I've already read them all about USB read/write and many of them use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`, but I think is not the answer. Please help me to find the right example of Write/Read file in USB Device from android.

Answer (score 0):

After googling and found a library from Magnus,
it totally clean for write/read from Usb Stick.

```
OutputStream os = UsbFileStreamFactory.createBufferedOutputStream(file, currentFs);
InputStream is = UsbFileStreamFactory.createBufferedInputStream(file, currentFs);
```

[Magnus - Libaums](https://github.com/magnusja/libaums)